# c++ rest sdk https server implemention (Windows)

Tags: ssl, https, sdk, server

I have dabbled with the c++ rest sdk for a while now and got around making a server and client fully.

The problem is that http requests from the client to the server seem to always be plaintext **so when i want to try logging in,**

**the URI is http://... login?email=anemail@gmail.com&password=123456**
I am new to network programming but ***this doesn't seem very secure*** and from what i understand https is the way to go... so far no info though as to how to setup a http over SSL server with casablanca c++ rest sdk.

Has anyone here tried to do this? maybe i need an additional library for this specifically?

Comment: The C++ REST SDK doesn't support HTTPS yet. Their server feature is still considered a beta feature and isn't finished.

Comment: So is there any way i can manually implement this without having to touch the REST SDK source or i have to scrap this project and start with another library like POCO?

Comment: SSL wouldn't resolve your issue entirely as it doesn't encrypt the URL, and you've put the password in the URL. You'd need to move that into the request headers or JSON payload in addition to using SSL.

Answer (score 2):

casablanca support HTTPS on the client side with  http_client on ALL platforms, it is only with the http_listener that HTTPS works on Windows only. To use https simply specify the scheme of the URI when constructing the http_client or http_listener object to be https, for example 'https://www.google.com'. and add ssl certificate to listening port.

Comment: It's actually not quite that simple to use HTTPS on the listener. You still need to manually add a certificate to the listening port.

Comment: yes.. user has to ad cert manually and code wise only make http_listener as https

Comment: How do I disable the certificate validation? I tried using set_validate_certificates(false), but that seems to be not working. Is there any other way?

Comment: Where did you find that HTTPS on the http_listener is supported on Windows? Would love to see the documentation and bring it up to Microsoft.

Comment: http://ib-krajewski.blogspot.in/2015/09/https-support-for-casablanca-server-and.html

Answer (score 1):

This is what I see in the http_listener code. It doesn't appear to support Windows at all.

```
#ifndef _WIN32
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the callback of ssl context
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The function defined by the user of http_listener_config to configure a ssl context.</returns>
    const std::function<void(boost::asio::ssl::context&)>& get_ssl_context_callback() const
    {
        return m_ssl_context_callback;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the callback of ssl context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ssl_context_callback">The function to configure a ssl context which will setup https connections.</param>
    void set_ssl_context_callback(const std::function<void(boost::asio::ssl::context&)> &ssl_context_callback)
    {
        m_ssl_context_callback = ssl_context_callback;
    }
#endif
```

Comment: I see this code, but there is nothing in document speaking about not support ssl in windows.

Comment: Yes, I know. However, I've spent the last few weeks trying to get SSL to work on Windows. I finally asked if this was the case in an issue on the Casablanca Github. The only response I received was that it appears to be unsupported.